# memtest.c linux

Tags: kernel, c, memory-management

I have basic knowledge of C and when studying [`memtest.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memtest.c), I can't understand the following - which the source code starts with:

```
 static u64 patterns[] __initdata = {
       /* The first entry has to be 0 to leave memtest with zeroed memory */
      0,
      0xffffffffffffffffULL,
      0x5555555555555555ULL,
      0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaULL,
      0x1111111111111111ULL,
      0x2222222222222222ULL,
      0x4444444444444444ULL,
      0x8888888888888888ULL,
      0x3333333333333333ULL,
      0x6666666666666666ULL,
      0x9999999999999999ULL,
      0xccccccccccccccccULL,
      0x7777777777777777ULL,
      0xbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbULL,
      0xddddddddddddddddULL,
      0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeULL,
      0x7a6c7258554e494cULL, /* yeah ;-) */
 };
```

And what about the comment `yeah ;-)` ? :-)

I have never seen this in C - how could it be explained and how is it used?

EDIT: now its more clear when u64 obviously is a typedef for long and ULL is a suffix for Unsigned Long Long. But the (representing) *memory addresses* of RAM in this array seems to be arbitrary choosen?

Comment: These aren't addresses. What's your question?

Comment: @roaima - hmmm missunderstanding or I have been unclear maybe ;-) ... in the context of pointers, yes its not addresses, but since memtest.c is testing ram for corrupt addresses - the array u64 (long) seem to **represent** addresses at some point of view. My question is how this array is used in the function? Probably the question should be migrated to stackoverflow with a c-tag?

Comment: You've got a satisfactory Answer now, I think. But no, these are not addresses; it's a block of data that's copied into memory addresses either long word at a time or as a block (I've not examined the source code)

Comment: As an aside, the `__initdata` *attribute* for the `patterns` array is interesting. In the kernel, it means memory that can be freed after kernel initialisation is complete. *PS* the `u64` type is specifically an unsigned value that is 64 bits wide - not necessarily a `long`.

Answer (score 4):

Those are not addresses in memory, those are test patterns. The memtest writes them to physical memory registers, reads back the data written, and compares it for errors.

---

If you translate them into binary in that order they appear in the c-snippet, it looks like this:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010
0001000100010001000100010001000100010001000100010001000100010001
0010001000100010001000100010001000100010001000100010001000100010
0100010001000100010001000100010001000100010001000100010001000100
1000100010001000100010001000100010001000100010001000100010001000
0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
0110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001
1100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100
0111011101110111011101110111011101110111011101110111011101110111
1011101110111011101110111011101110111011101110111011101110111011
1101110111011101110111011101110111011101110111011101110111011101
1110111011101110111011101110111011101110111011101110111011101110
0111101001101100011100100101100001010101010011100100100101001100
```

I replaced the 0s with spaces and then, you may see the pattern better:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1  
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11
 11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11 
1  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  1
11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  
 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111
1 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 11
11 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 1
111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 
 1111 1  11 11   111  1  1 11    1 1 1 1 1  111  1  1  1 1  11
```

It shifts the 1s and 0s in the memory adresses. This is a rather common technique to stress test physical memory. Each bit has to flip multiple times.

The last pattern doesn't fit the rest. See @purplepsycho [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248289/52727) what that means. This is the last pattern, which then stays in tested memory.

---

You can copy that first part into a `file` and run this `awk` on it, for a briefly demonstration, what happens in memory (0s removed):

```
awk '{ORS="\r"; system("sleep 0.5"); gsub("0", " ", $0);}1' file
```

Answer (score 3):

> And what about the comment `/* yeah ;-) */`

The `0x7a6c7258554e494c` integer can be decoded in (Ascii) `zlrXINUL`, ("LINUX rules" in reverse).

This statement declares an array of 17 64 bits unsigned integers. I think that all of these integers will be written and read in each all memory space to check that no bit is lost in the operation.

The address of the array is chosen by the compiler in program memory, and the program will chose explicitly each address in RAM to be tested.

Next question : how to test the memory on which the program is stored? Will kernel move the program by playing with pagination or segmentation?

Comment: seem to be the answer I have been looking for - it make sense that it use these integers in testing memory. Did not think of that :-)

Comment: x86 being little endian, that means that "LINUXrlz" will be in the correct order in the memory.